# Convert nested dict to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a nested dict to dataframe

```
{
    '2022-09-08T15:00:00Z': {
        'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M':
          {
            "DVENTO": [
                {'value' : '95.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag': 'GOOD','structure' : 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M', 'element' : 'DVENTO'}],
            "TD_MN_C":[
                {'value' : '6.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag': 'GOOD','structure' : 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M', 'element' : 'TD_MN_C'},]
            },
    },
    '2022-09-09T12:00:00Z': {
        'INMET_GOIANIA_A002_M':
        {
            "DVENTO" : [
                {'value' : '25', 'quality' : 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag' : 'GOOD', 'structure' : 'INMET_GOIANIA_A002_M', 'element' : 'DVENTO' }],
            "TD_MN_C":[{
                'value' : '3.0', 'quality' : 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag' : 'GOOD', 'structure' : 'INMET_GOIANIA_A002_M', 'element' : 'TD_MN_C'}],

        },
    }
}
```

I had this nested dict and now i want to convert to dataframe, something like this

```
                       DVENTO     TD_MN_C
2022-09-08T15:00:00Z    95.0        6.0
2022-09-09T12:00:00Z    25          3.0
```

please help me, I've been trying this for days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve the desired output.

Assuming that the dictionary is stored in the variable `dictionary`, one can start by doing the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index').stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

[Out]:

                                                                 DVENTO                                            TD_MN_C
2022-09-08T15:00:00Z  [{'value': '95.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'qual...  [{'value': '6.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quali...
2022-09-09T12:00:00Z  [{'value': '25', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'qualit...  [{'value': '3.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quali...
```

Then, as one wants the cells of `DVENTO` and `TD_MN_C` to be the `value` from the list with the dictionary obtained before in each cell, one can simply use list comprehensions as follows

```
df['DVENTO'] = [x[0]['value'] for x in df['DVENTO']]
df['TD_MN_C'] = [x[0]['value'] for x in df['TD_MN_C']]

[Out]:

                     DVENTO TD_MN_C
2022-09-08T15:00:00Z   95.0     6.0
2022-09-09T12:00:00Z     25     3.0
```

A one-liner would be like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index').stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).applymap(lambda x: x[0]['value'] if isinstance(x, list) else x)

[Out]:

                     DVENTO TD_MN_C
2022-09-08T15:00:00Z   95.0     6.0
2022-09-09T12:00:00Z     25     3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This should answer your question:

```py
import pandas as pd


data = {
    '2022-09-08T15:00:00Z': {
        'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M':
          {
            "DVENTO": [
                {'value' : '95.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag': 'GOOD','structure' : 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M', 'element' : 'DVENTO'}],
            "TD_MN_C":[
                {'value' : '6.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag': 'GOOD','structure' : 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M', 'element' : 'TD_MN_C'},]
            },
    },
    '2022-09-09T12:00:00Z': {
        'INMET_GOIANIA_A002_M':
        {
            "DVENTO" : [
                {'value' : '25', 'quality' : 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag' : 'GOOD', 'structure' : 'INMET_GOIANIA_A002_M', 'element' : 'DVENTO' }],
            "TD_MN_C":[{
                'value' : '3.0', 'quality' : 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag' : 'GOOD', 'structure' : 'INMET_GOIANIA_A002_M', 'element' : 'TD_MN_C'}],

        },
    }
}


data_2 = {k:v[list(v.keys())[0]] for k,v in data.items()}
data_3 = {k:{k2:v2[0]['value'] for k2,v2 in v.items()}  for k,v in data_2.items()}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_3).transpose()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     DVENTO TD_MN_C
2022-09-08T15:00:00Z   95.0     6.0
2022-09-09T12:00:00Z     25     3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Roll out a for loop for clarity and performance:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

content = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in data.items():
    content['dates'].append(key)
        for k, v in value.items():
            for ki, vi in v.items():
                content[ki].append(vi[0]['value'])

print(content)
defaultdict(list,
            {'dates': ['2022-09-08T15:00:00Z', '2022-09-09T12:00:00Z'],
             'DVENTO': ['95.0', '25'],
             'TD_MN_C': ['6.0', '3.0']})

pd.DataFrame(content)
                  dates DVENTO TD_MN_C
0  2022-09-08T15:00:00Z   95.0     6.0
1  2022-09-09T12:00:00Z     25     3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt1=pd.Series(data).map(lambda x:pd.Series(x).iat[0]).to_dict()
pd.DataFrame().from_dict(dt1,orient='index').applymap(lambda x:x[0]['value'])
```

output：

```
                     DVENTO TD_MN_C
2022-09-08T15:00:00Z   95.0     6.0
2022-09-09T12:00:00Z     25     3.0
```